# Python: class 3-opt of TSP is very slow - speeding up permutation creation

Tags: python, loops, oop

I am implementing a TSP with Precedence Constraints in Python. These two classes are supposed to perform a simple 3-opt move and then create the corresponding neighborhood structure (that is all possible 3-opt permutations of an initial tour).

Pretty much everything here is an object (i.e initial_tour is an instance of a Tour()-class with the attribute tour.tour_permutation which is a ordered list of Node()-objects)

I guess the reason my code works so slowly is because I iterate through all possible permutations with inefficient code. What are possibilities to speed this up ?

```
class ThreeOpt:
    def __init__(self, initial_tour):
      self.initial_tour = list(node.node_id for node in initial_tour.tour_permutation)

  def perform_move(self, i, j, k):
      n = len(self.initial_tour)
      a = self.initial_tour[0:i]
      b = self.initial_tour[i:j]
      c = self.initial_tour[j:k]
      d = self.initial_tour[k:n+1]


      move2 = a + list(reversed(b)) + c + d
      move3 = a + b + list(reversed(c)) + d
      move4 = a + list(reversed(b)) + list(reversed(c)) + d
      move5 = a + c + b + d
      move6 = a + c + list(reversed(b)) + d
      move7 = a + list(reversed(c)) + b + d
      move8 = a + list(reversed(c)) + list(reversed(b)) + d

      return [move2, move3, move4, move5, move6, move7, move8]

class ThreeOptNeighborhood(BaseNeighborhood):
    def __init__(self, graph, initial_tour, evaluation_logic, tour_pool): #everything here is defined
        self().__init__(graph, initial_tour, evaluation_logic, tour_pool)
        self.type = '3-opt'
        self.initial_tour = list(node.node_id for node in initial_tour.tour_permutation)

    def discover_tours(self):
        three_opt = ThreeOpt(self.initial_tour)
        for i in range(1, len(self.initial_tour.tour_permutation) - 2):
            for j in range(i + 1, len(self.initial_tour.tour_permutation) - 1):
                for k in range(j + 1, len(self.initial_tour.tour_permutation)):
                    new_tour_permutations = three_opt.perform_move(i, j, k)
                    for new_tour_permutation in new_tour_permutations:
                        self.moves.append(new_tour_permutation)``
```